# How to perform builk update within mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, bulk

I have been trying to perform a bulk update using a single update query but unable to do so within the stored procedure.
Following is the bulk update query that run flawlessly

```
UPDATE `batch_requests_detail`
SET `processing_status` = 5
WHERE `batch_requests_detail_id`  IN (1,2,3);
```

Where as when I use it within the stored procedure it didn't work

```
CALL Update_Batch_Request_Detail_Bulk('1,2,3',10);

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `Update_Batch_Request_Detail_Bulk`(
IN _batch_request_detail_ids VARCHAR(5000),
IN _processing_status INT
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE `batch_requests_detail`
    SET `processing_status` = _processing_status
    WHERE `batch_requests_detail_id`  IN (_batch_request_detail_ids);
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that _batch_request_detail_ids = "1,2,3", try this :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `Update_Batch_Request_Detail_Bulk`(
IN _batch_request_detail_ids VARCHAR(5000),
IN _processing_status INT
)
BEGIN
     /**************** Set statement added***********/
    SET @sql =concat("UPDATE batch_requests_detail
    SET processing_status = ",_processing_status," 
    WHERE batch_requests_detail_id  IN (",_batch_request_detail_ids,");");
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this but Concat isn't working.
 I tried using single quote like this    @sql =  CONCAT('UPDATE batch_requests_detail SET processing_status = ', _processing_status , ' WHERE batch_requests_detail_id  IN (' , _batch_request_detail_ids , ');');
 But it didn't work too.

Comment: ok got it Set statement was missing.